# Ubuntu Terminal: "apt-get" invalid syntax

Tags: command-line, apt, mariadb

I have just recently installed Ubuntu onto my new laptop, following all steps correctly during installation, installing new applications and drivers from online. Upon finishing installing Ubuntu, I attepmted to install MariaDB via the terminal by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

and then the following error is returned:

```
sudo apt-get install software-propterties-common
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sudo apt-get install software-propterties-common
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can i get my termianl to function correctly?

Comment: You should include more context in the question. If you had pasted the previous and following couple of lines, the answer would have been obvious to most people here. The way you asked it, only someone who happens to have used lots of Python lately was likely to understand.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are running the command in a Python interpreter. The command is supposed to be run in a shell. If you are still at the Python interpreter, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or type `exit()` to quit the interpreter and return to the shell, or Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new terminal. Execute the command there.

Comment: Wow, stupid mistake, thankyou for the fix!

Comment: No mistake is stupid :) Glad to help